# ngTagsInput CSS issue

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ng-tags-input

I'm using [ngTagsInput](https://github.com/mbenford/ngTagsInput) plugin to render some autocomplete tags. I have used this in one of my previous projects and worked fine.

However, in my new project, when I add the `ngTagsInput` CSS, it does not show the text area for user to type tags. I checked the CSS and couldn't find anything overrides the `ngTagsInput` CSS.

Please have a look at the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/cN9iDD?p=preview) I've created to demonstrate the issue. It shows only the button, but not the `tags-input` directive.

How can I fix this CSS?

Comment: Can be put on hold under: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have forgotten to include the JS file and add the module dependency.

**index.html**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-tags-input/2.3.0/ng-tags-input.min.js"></script>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'ngTagsInput'])
```

See next [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MHLeFdiOISLrUWT8T4gA?p=preview)